# spring security, tomcat, getRemoteUser method

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-security

i've got two applications in same tomcat. one of those applications uses spring security for authentication. i would like method getRemoteUser to return valid user name in second application when logged into first one.

is there easy way to achieve this? can u please point me out to simplest possible solution which will do that?

thanks for responses

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe Application 2 can access application 1's security information.  Not directly anyways, perhaps using remoting, or webservices will allow you to do this.  However, I do not think there is a place in the spring security framework where you can go across applications and get information though java code only.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the local current logged in user:

```
String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
    .getAuthentication().getName();
```

So, if **appA** is logged in into **appB** then exposing this controller will return the username, the one used in appA to login into appB. Wich appA should already know, mmmm:

```
public class UserController extends AbstractController {

  @Override
  protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
   HttpServletResponse res) throws Exception {
      String username = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
          .getAuthentication().getName();
      ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("jsonResponse");
      mv.addObject("username", username);
      return mv;
  }
}
```

Comment: i was rather thinking about some kind of single sign on solution so that tomcat can share the information about security. i'm not quite sure how to use SingleSignOn valve in tomcat :/

Comment: OK. I just finished a SSO Project using CAS SSO, Tomcat and Spring Security. It’s really easy to setup and it works great.
http://www.jasig.org/cas